# Modal from another Modal form not working in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Am trying to show a modal form from another modal form. However i get the new modal form displayed but at the backside of the old modal form. How to get the new modal form shown in front of all. Please help. Thanks in advance. Below is my code

```
$('#modal1').modal('show');
```

Comment: Please share more code, so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/wtj6nacd/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#openBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal({
      show: true
    })
  });

  $(document).on({
    'show.bs.modal': function() {
      var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
      $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
      }, 0);
    },
    'hidden.bs.modal': function() {
      if ($('.modal:visible').length > 0) {
        // restore the modal-open class to the body element, so that scrolling works
        // properly after de-stacking a modal.
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }, '.modal');
});
```

```css
/* crazy batman newspaper spinny thing */

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.rotate.in {
  transform: rotate(1800deg);
  transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>more content</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="modal-body">Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>come content</p>
        <br>
        <br>
      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.